# Largest value of $P(X =4)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Consider $4$ trials each having same probability of success. Let $X$ denote the total number of successes in these trials, if $\mathbb{E}(X) = 2$, what is

A) the maximum value of $P(X =4)$

B) the minimum value of $P(X = 4)$

I don’t really know how to approach this question, all i did was say that
$\mathbb{E}(X) = np = 4p =2$
Which gives $p =\frac{1}{2}$ so $P(X =4)=\frac{1}{16}$ but this is not correct and I don’t know how to do the second part either

Comment: I guess you assumed Independence which is not mentioned in the hypothesis

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve this question without assuming independence?

Comment: If you call $S_i$, $1\leq i \leq 4$ the event of success in the $i$-th trial, then
$$P(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4) = P(S_1) \cdot P(S_2|S_1) \cdot P(S_3|S_1\cap S_2) \cdot P(S_4|S_1\cap S_2 \cap S_3).$$
You already noted that $P(S_i) = \frac{1}{2}$, since the expected value does not vary depending of the conditioned probabilities, which can have any value between $0$ and $1$ included, I would say. So my conclusion, without any other information is
$$0 \leq P(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4) \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I would say this is compatible with the situation. In other words: $P(X=0) = P(X=4) = 0$  and $P(X=1) = P(X=2) = \frac{1}{2}$, on one side, and $P(X=0) = P(X=4) = \frac{1}{2}$  and $P(X=1) = P(X=2) = 0$ on the other, both give $E[X] = 2$.

Comment: I have the same question with parameters $n = 3$ $\mathbb{E}(X = 1.8)$ and the same two questions are asked for $P(X = 3)$ and the answer is also given to be $0.6$

Comment: Yes, same story. Does my answer agree with your book's. Maybe I should post it as an answer...

Comment: The book that I am using says that the answer for the posted question is 1/4

Comment: Mmmm. Ok, I'll think it over, then :)

Comment: my previous comment was missing the value of $P(X=3)$, anyway.. sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91674/discussion-between-matteo-and-user601297).

Answer (score 1):

Even though my answer does not agree with the one given in your book, I will post it here, to see if someone else in the community finds the error in my approach

---

If you call $S_i$, $1\leq i \leq 4$ the event of success in the $i$-th trial, then
$$P(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4) = P(S_1) \cdot P(S_2|S_1) \cdot P(S_3|S_1\cap S_2) \cdot P(S_4|S_1\cap S_2 \cap S_3).$$
You already noted that $P(S_i) = \frac{1}{2}$, so we must have
$$0 \leq P(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4) \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

---

Let us see two scenarios in which extreme values are attained.

1. Two urns containing $4$ black balls and $4$ white balls, respectively.
2. Two urns, one containing $1$ black ball and $3$ white balls, one containing $3$ back balls and $1$ white ball.

In both cases, pick randomly one urn and extract $4$ balls and let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of, say, black balls extracted.

In the first scenario $P(X = 0) = P(X=4) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=1) = P(X=2) = P(X=3) = 0$.

In the second scenario $P(X=0) = P(X=2) = P(X=4) = 0$ and $P(X=1) = P(X=3) = \frac{1}{2}$.

So in both cases $\Bbb E[X]=2$.

Let us now check $P(S_i)$, which is given by
$$P(S_i) = \frac{P(S_i|U_1) + P(S_i|U_2)}{2},$$
$U_1$ and $U_2$ being the event of picking first and second urn respectively.

In the first scenario $P(S_i|U_1) = 1$ and $P(S_i|U_2) = 0$, so that $P(S_i) = \frac{1}{2}.$

In the second scenario $P(S_i|U_1) = \frac{1}{4}$ and $P(S_i|U_2) = \frac{3}{4}$. Thus, again $P(S_i) = \frac{1}{2}$ as required.